# Fit model with custom function and parameters

Tags: r, generics, parameters, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I want to use robust non-linear regression in R to fit some data (nlrob). However, I think this question should be valid also for non-robust and/or linear methods.

I wrote a custom function that return the value of the dependent variable as a function of the independent variable plus some extra parameters. My problem is that, for each "case", I can have different number of extra parameters. How can I encode that?

Exemple:

case 1

```
 nlrob(y ~ f(x, p,p1),data = data1, start = c(p1 = 0 ))
```

case 2

```
nlrob(y ~ f(x,p, p1,p2,p3),data = data2, start = c(p1 = 0,p2 = 0,p3 = 0 ))
```

How should I write function f such that it can received and parse x, p, and a arbitrary of p*? How to write the nlrob line in order for this to work? In another words, how to write the generic lines of the calls to nlrob and function f for arbitrary number of parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients can be a vector.  For example, here the `p` argument of `f` can be of length 1 or 2:

```
f <- function(x, p) if (length(p) == 1) p * x else p[1] * x + p[2]
nlrob(demand ~ f(Time, p), BOD, start = list(p = 1))
nlrob(demand ~ f(Time, p), BOD, start = list(p = 1:2))
```

### Added:

To use with `method = "tau"`, say, define `upper` and `lower` instead of `start`:

```
# lower <- 0; upper <- 10
lower <- c(0, 0); upper <- c(10, 10)

nms <- paste0("p", seq_along(upper))
names(lower) <- names(upper) <- nms
f <- function(x, ...) {
   with(list(...), if (...length() == 1) p1 * x else p1 * x + p2)
}   
fo <- sprintf("demand ~ f(Time, %s)", toString(paste(nms, "=", nms)))
nlrob(fo, data = BOD, lower = lower, upper = upper, method = "tau")
```

Comment: Great!!! That actually works :) I will accept the answer. However, this does not work if I want to use any method that is not M. In that case I have to specific lower and upper bounds and that did not work. Do you have a workaround for that? (By the way, anyone know the best method?)

Comment: What does *method that is not M* mean?

Comment: On nlrob we can select the method. By default it's an M-estimator. However, as far as I understood there are better methods available, as for example Maximum trimmed likelihood. The implementation of all this other methods assume that, instead of defining the starting point, the user should provided the boundaries.

Comment: See Added section.